# Close slide-to-top accordion on its content

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, accordion

I've been using the [Flexible Slide-to-top Accordion](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/12/flexible-slide-to-top-accordion/) to build my page.

At first I used the option to only have one opened at the time. I'm not at all an expert on jQuery so this was a bit of a challenge for me. But finally got it up running and felt done, and then I noticed the slide-to-top on iOS was all bonkers. This was not a biggie, it was a pretty awkward animation when I had so much content.

So I decided to go with that if one of them is open the other ones won't collapse. This made a smoother animation.

But. After you've scrolled for a while and want to close it, you have to scroll all the way up again. I want a much simpler solution, where you can close it wherever you want. Not an extra button, just anywhere on its content.

So, to my question. How can I bind just the closing part to anywhere I want? If it is easier with a button that could do to, but I have a thing thought out with custom cursor showing that you can close anywhere you want.

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe someone just know how to put a closebutton at the end of the content? That would be close enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tied .theaccordion-content to click event, check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/kzeKd/), I used code from your site.

```
  // open / close item
  this.$items.find('a:first, .theaccordion-content').bind('click.accordion', function (event) {

     var $item = $(this).parent();

     // close any opened item if oneOpenedItem is true
     if (instance.options.oneOpenedItem && instance._isOpened() && instance.current !== $item.index()) {

          instance._toggleItem(instance.$items.eq(instance.current));

     }

     // open / close item
     instance._toggleItem($item);

     return false;

   });
```

---

Tip: You should change:

```
<section id="themargin"></section>
```

to

```
<section class="themargin"></section>
```

because you have duplicate ID's and that's not a valid HTML.